# Memory leak linked list

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, linked-list

I'm having issue with an assignment for my CS class. I've been working with a friend, and we've identified that our code has a memory leak, but we can't find what the problem is. Essentially, the code is supposed to create a linked list with digits from 2-1000. Then, the code uses deletemultiples in order to delete numbers that aren't prime. It does this by taking a number and deleting any multiples of that number in the linked list. When we used valgrind, it returned a memory leak.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct node{
    int info;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;

node *inserthead(node *head, int a);
node *inserttail(node *head, int a);
node *deletemultiples(node *head, int a);
void printlist(node *head);
void freelist(node *head);

int main(){

    node *head1 = NULL;
    int i,j;
    for(i = 2;i <= 1000;i++)
        head1 = inserttail(head1,i);
    for(i = 2; i <= 32; i++){
        head1 = deletemultiples(head1,i);
    }
    printlist(head1);
    freelist(head1);
}

node *inserthead(node *head, int a){
    node *ptr;

    ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->info = a;
    ptr->next = head;

    return(ptr);
}

node *inserttail(node *head, int a){
    node *ptr;
    node *ptr2 = head;

    ptr = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    ptr->info = a;
    ptr->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL)
        return(ptr);
    else if (head->next == NULL){
        head->next = ptr;
        return(head);
    }
    while(head->next != NULL)
        head = head->next;

    head->next = ptr;
    return(ptr2);
}

void printlist(node *head){
    while(head!=NULL){
        printf("%i ",head->info);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void freelist(node *head){
    node *ptr = head;
    while(head != NULL){
        head = head->next;
        free(ptr);
        ptr = head;
    }
}

node *deletemultiples(node *head, int a){
  node *ptr = head, *temp = head;

  while (ptr != NULL) {
      if(ptr->info % a > 0){
        ptr = ptr->next;
        temp = temp->next;
      }
      else{
        ptr = ptr->next;
        temp->next = ptr;
      }
    }

  return(head);

}
```

If anyone can help us figure out what we did wrong, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at deletemultiples. You'll see that you are not deleting anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `deletemultiples()` function never frees the nodes it unlinks, so `freelist()` never reaches them when it walks the list to delete it.  Delete the nodes you remove the same way you did in `freelist()`.

Alternatively, you could create an array of 1,000 nodes (It’s a good habit to turn constants like that into symbolic names.) and link and unlink nodes within that array as weak references.  You would free the entire array in a single call when you destroy all lists that depend on it.

Kudos for looking for memory leaks in your code.  It’ll save you a lot of grief.

Comment: That makes sense, I thought something was missing in deletemultiples. I'll check it out and get back to you, thanks a lot!